# Write a C program to convert 1D array to 2D array using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Write a C program to convert 1D array to 2D array using pointers.
Follow the given steps to implement the above code.

1. Ask the user to input the number of rows (​ m ​ ) and the number of columns (​ n ​ ) of the 2D array.
   So the total number of elements of 1D array = (​ m * n ​ ) elements.
2. Call the function​ ​ input_array​ to store elements in 1D array.

   `void input_array (int *arr,int size)   // size = ​ m * n`
3. Call the function ​ print_array​ to print the elements of 1D array.

   `void print_array (int *arr, int size)`
4. Call the function ​ array_to_matrix​ to convert 1D array to 2D array.

   `void array_to_matrix(int **matrix, int *arr, int row, int col)`
5. Call function ​ print_matrix​ to print the elements of the 2D array.

   `void print_matrix(int **mat, int row, int col)`

All functions should be called from the main(). Accessing and storing of elements in pointers should be carried out by using pointers only.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 100

void input_array (int *arr,int size);
void print_array (int *arr, int size);
void array_to_matrix(int **matrix, int *arr, int row, int col);
void print_matrix(int **matrix, int row, int col);


int main()
{
    int m, n, arr[max], mat[max][max];
    printf("Enter the number of rows(m):");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter the number of columns(n):");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int size = m*n;

    input_array (arr,size);
    print_array (arr,size);
    array_to_matrix(mat, arr, m, n);
    print_matrix(mat, m, n);
}

void input_array (int *arr,int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter element a[%d]",i);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);    
    }
}

void print_array (int *arr, int size)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n 1D array is as follows : \n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
}

void array_to_matrix(int **matrix, int *arr, int row, int col)
{
    int i,j,k=0;     
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = arr[k];
            k++;
        }
    }

}

void print_matrix(int **matrix, int row, int col)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("\n 2D matrix is as follows : \n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**Error:**
I am getting a segmentation fault. The problem I am having is related to pointer to the arrays and how to pass them to the function.

Comment: what an idea to do `int size = m*n;` while n nor m are yet intialized

Comment: so should int size = m*n; come after m and n are taken?

Comment: you cannot do the multiplication before to have n and m values yes, but this is not the only error in your code, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

> ```
> void main()
> {
>     int m, n, arr[max], mat[max][max];
>     int size = m*n;
> ```

you compute *size* while *m* and *n* are not yet (possibly) initialized, so the value of *size* is undefined with undefined behavior

In

> ```
>  void array_to_matrix(int **matrix, int *arr, int row, int col)
>  {
>      int i,j,k=0;     
>      for(i=0;i<row;i++)
>      {
>          for(j=0;j<col;j++)
>          {
>              matrix[i][j] = arr[k];
>          }
>      }
>  }
> ```

the signature of the function says *matrix* is an array of pointers to *int*, but this is not compatible with your *main* where you use a 2D array. To be compatible :

```
void array_to_matrix(int (*matrix)[max], int *arr, int row, int col)
```

and same for *print_matrix* :

```
void print_matrix(int (*matrix)[max], int row, int col)
```

or if you prefer :

```
void array_to_matrix(int matrix[][max], int *arr, int row, int col)
void print_matrix(int matrix[][max], int row, int col)
```

But :

> Write a C program to convert 1D array to **2D array using pointers**

"*2D array using pointers*" is an is an abuse of language and means a 1D array of pointer to *int*, there is no 2D array.

In your previous version you limited the dimensions to 100, you do not have a reason to do that, just allocate the arrays in the heap.

Note also *k* always values 0 in *array_to_matrix*, so you always use `arr[0]`

And :

> ```
> void main()
> ```

is wrong, *main* returns an *int*

I also encourage you to *always* check the result of *scanf* to be sure a valid input was used, else you works with non initialized value with an undefined behavior. When you read the number of rows and columns check there are not less than 1

In *print_array* to separate the print value with a space will help to make the result readable

Finaly :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input_array (int *arr,int size);
void print_array (int *arr, int size);
void array_to_matrix(int ** matrix, int *arr, int row, int col);
void print_matrix(int ** matrix, int row, int col);


int main()
{
    int m, n, * arr, ** mat;
    int size, i;

    printf("Enter the number of rows(m):");
    if ((scanf("%d",&m) != 1) || (m < 1)) {
      puts("invalid value for rows");
      return -1;
    }

    printf("Enter the number of columns(n):");
    if ((scanf("%d",&n) != 1) || (n < 1)) {
      puts("invalid value for columns");
      return -1;
    }

    size = m*n;
    if (((arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int))) == NULL) ||
        ((mat = malloc(m * sizeof(int))) == NULL)) {
      puts("not enouh memory");
      exit(-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
      if ((mat[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
        puts("not enouh memory");
        exit(-1);
      }
    }
    input_array (arr,size);
    print_array (arr,size);
    array_to_matrix(mat, arr, m, n);
    print_matrix(mat, m, n);

    /* free resources */
    free(arr);
    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
      free(mat[i]);
    free(mat);

    return 0;
}

void input_array (int *arr,int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter element a[%d]",i);
        if (scanf("%d",&arr[i]) != 1) {
          int c;

          puts("invalid value, redo");

          /* flush invalid value up to the end of line */
          while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
            if (c == EOF) {
              puts("EOF, abort");
              exit(-1);
            }
          }

          i -= 1;
        }
    }
}

void print_array (int *arr, int size)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n 1D array is as follows : \n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}

void array_to_matrix(int ** matrix, int *arr, int row, int col)
{
    int i,j,k=0;     
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = arr[k++];
        }
    }

}

void print_matrix(int ** matrix, int row, int col)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("\n 2D matrix is as follows : \n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the number of rows(m):2
Enter the number of columns(n):aze
invalid value for columns
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the number of rows(m):-1
invalid value for rows
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the number of rows(m):2
Enter the number of columns(n):3
Enter element a[0]1
Enter element a[1]aa
invalid value, redo
Enter element a[1]2
Enter element a[2]3
Enter element a[3]4
Enter element a[4]5
Enter element a[5]6

 1D array is as follows : 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
 2D matrix is as follows : 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: i have changed it to k++. But how to deal with **matrix??

Comment: @Alpha I edited my answer signaling problems and giving a solution, note the statement of you r problem is wrong